# Show that there is a bounded linear functional $\ell : \mathscr C [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $\lVert \ell \rVert \leq 1,\ \ell(1)=0,\ \ell(\cos(x))=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

The title says it all. I've been assuming that the best way to do this is constructively, by finding such an $\ell$. I have by a theorem in our class that since $\lVert \cos(x)\rVert =1$, we know that there exists some bdd linear functional $T$ such that $T(\cos(x))=1$ and $\lVert T \rVert =1$. But that doesn't get me very far.

I think my failure to find an answer is just a failure of imagination, in thinking up an appropriate $\ell$. So I'd appreciate, in any answers or comments, tips not just about what $\ell$ satisfies the conditions here but also about how to come up with such an $\ell$.

(Edited to fix typo pointed out by @xyzzyz.)

Comment: The problem looks broken. Since $||\cos|| = 1$ for $\cos \in \mathcal{C}[0, 1]$, and $||\mathcal{l}(\cos)|| = ||1|| = 1$, it already implies that $||\mathcal{l}|| \geq 1$.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed the typo: $<$ should have been $\leq$.

Comment: Then it follows straight from Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Also, the result is not true as it is stated: If we can find $\ell$, then we'd have $1=|\ell(\cos(x)-1)|\leq\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\cos(x)-1|<1$. I guess you want $\cos(2\pi x)$ instead of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro The problem was stated as I gave it above on an exam that I took. On that exam I received full credit for my response to the problem despite the fact that my response appears to me to fail to provide the requested proof. I think your comment, more than anything else here, clarifies for me what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there seems to be an issue with the statement of the problem. However, the general idea seems to be that the bounded linear functionals on $C[0,1]$ separate points. This follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Also, the statement of the problem is ``show that there exists...'' which leads me to believe an explicit example is not necessary.

Comment: This was an exam problem from a course I took two terms ago. I believe that the professor gave an explicit example as an answer when explaining the exam after handing it back. Wish I had recorded it in my notes though!

Comment: If it was $\cos(2\pi x)$, you could use $\ell(f)=<f,\cos(2\pi\cdot)>$